# Using Tor for the whole system on fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

Can I "port" the Tor network in order to use it through the whole system (updates, using in different browser, etc) ??

I'm using linux (Fedora 21 64 bit)

Comment: Guess not. Tor cannot anonymize UDP connections. Tails is an approach, but its way more than tor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can route all data through Tor, but is a **Bad Idea.**

Instead try [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) a live operating system, that you can start on almost any computer from a DVD, USB stick, or SD card. It aims at preserving your privacy and anonymity, and helps you to:

- use the Internet anonymously and circumvent censorship;
  all connections to the Internet are forced to go through the Tor network;
- leave no trace on the computer you are using unless you ask it explicitly;
  use state-of-the-art cryptographic tools to encrypt your files, emails and instant messaging.

The problem with routing all traffic through Tor is that the programs are not audited to run through Tor without leaking any information. The same applies to browsers that are not Tor Browser Bundle. You also end up using Tor bandwidth on unimportant things such as updates and what not.

Comment: You're saying routing all data via Tor is a bad idea, and yet, you suggest using Tails, which, if I'm correct, does exactly that!