# How to direct the entire computer's internet traffic through Tor?

Tags: pluggable-transports, web-proxy

I would like to direct the entire computer's internet traffic exclusively through Tor. What options do exist that allow the entire internet traffic exclusively through Tor? And what is the step by step process to accomplish this task?

Comment: Hi there; welecome to Tor.SE. There are several questions already that exist to answer this question (for various Linux distros, OpenWRT, Windows, etc.). If you think your question is somehow different from those, or those answers don't fit, please differentiate your question so that we can try to give you an accurate answer, and then nominate this question for re-opening. Thanks!

Comment: Try using [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/). Feel free to view [my answer](http://tor.stackexchange.com/a/6029/696) on another question which explains why tails is a good idea.